# how to load NSTableView when nib is loaded?

Tags: objective-c

I have an appllication in which when I click on NSButton of one nib,another nib loaded,and that second nib contains an NSTableView. which I need to load just after second nib loaded.

But I am Not able to do so. If I put that code in awakeFromNib then NSTableView again get initialize. its really a mesh I m not getting...

So,plz help me out.

Answer (score -1):

If the File's Owner of the second nib is a `UIViewController` (which it most likely is), you could create the `NSTableView` inside the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but actually I am working on cocoa application.
So , I am using NSWindowcontroller. I also try to put code in applicationDidFinishLaunching but still it do not work.